# Division By Zero

Tags: php, divide-by-zero

I'm using a method to calculate some scores. This is the following method:

```
public function getIntScore($name, $int){
    switch ($name) {
        case "bedrooms":
            $maxscore = 15;
            break;
        case "living_size":
            $maxscore = 10;
            break;
        case "property_size":
            $maxscore = 10;
            break;
        case "date_of_construction":
            $maxscore = 3;
            break;
    }
    $houseattribute = (int) $this->$name;
    $difference = abs($houseattribute - $int);
    if ($difference == 0) {
        return $maxscore;
    }
    $score = ($difference / $houseattribute) * $maxscore;
    return round($score);
}
```

However, this gives me a "Division by zero" error. I checked the values of the variables before calculating and none of them are zero.

```
var_dump($difference, $houseattribute, $maxscore)
```

outputs:

```
int(2) int(3) int(15)
```

Comment: Are you checked just before `$score = ($difference / $houseattribute) * $maxscore;`? 
Are you totally sure division by zero throws in this line?

Comment: Yes, I checked it just before that line. Yii gives me an error on line 878, which is the line `$score = ($difference / $houseattribute) * $maxscore;` is on.

Comment: Could you try `$score = ($difference / ($houseattribute + 1)) * $maxscore;`?

Comment: What do you try to accomplish with ``$houseattribute = (int) $name;`` This would turn a string into an integer, and result in 0.

Comment: @neworld This works and results in no error. This is strange behaviour, as `$houseattribute` was not 0.
@Narretz `$this->$name` returns string "3" in this example, casting this to int gives me 3.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is on the line $houseattribute = (int) $this->$name; What could the value possibly be? What is the value you expect this to output?

Comment: As per your comment, you do not need to convert the string to an integer ($houseattribute = (int) $this->$name). You say the value of $this->$name is "3". In PHP, 3 == "3" eg: if (3 == "3"){die("yes");} Three equals compares type (===). So the (int) is not needed. Don't know if that will fix the problem though

Comment: Just made a var_dump() of the $houseattribute variable, which returned int(3). Are you sure the problem is on that line, as it doesn't give me any errors and simply converts a string to an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I was stupid enough to forget I was looping through an array, where the first `$houseattribute` was `3`. I had an item in my array where `$houseattribute` was `0`, but because I used `exit;` after dumping the variables I didn't know it was. I changed it to a positive integer and not it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you test for empty values:

```
$houseattribute = (int) $this->$name;
if (empty($houseattribute)) {
   throw new Exception('House attribute is zero.');
}
```

Comment: Adding your code results in the given exception. However, I do not understand this. If I use `echo $houseattribute;` or `var_dump($houseattribute);` it results in respectively `3` or `int(3)`. Why does the `empty()` function return `true`?

Comment: There might be some unseen characters at the beginning, and the cast fails to decode the string to number because the first char it encounters it is not a number. Try echoing the variable char by char.

Comment: I'm afraid there are no unseen characters. I used `substr($houseattribute, 0, 1);` to get the first character, and it resulted in `3`. Then, I checked if the cast was being executed correctly by using `var_dump($houseattribute, (int)$houseattribute);`. This resulted in `string(1) "3" int(3)`.

Comment: I'm afraid this is a PHP bug. Try to make some simple example in other file: `$a = (int)'3home' ....` Or try to change PHP version